# Override a PowerShell parameter's parsing mode?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Assuming this function:

```
function Get-Foo {

    param(
        [string[]]$Foos
    )

    Foreach ($Foo IN $Foos) {
        Write-Host "Foo: $Foo"
    }

}
```

Calling this function with string delimiters (`'`) creates an array:

```
PS> Get-Foo -Foos 'ABC 1', 'DEF 2'
Foo: ABC 1
Foo: DEF 2
```

Calling it without the delimiters produces an error:

```
PS> Get-Foo -Foos ABC 1, DEF 2
Get-Foo : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Foo -Foos ABC 1, DEF 2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Foo], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Get-Foo
```

Is there a way to over-ride the parameter's parsing logic to enable both case to function as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This isn't a function of the function definition, this is how the language is parsed and interpreted.

These classes are actually available for you to use in PowerShell as well, so you could see how they work, but changing them isn't all that practical. You could make your own parser and then maybe use the AST to execute the tokens? But then you'd have to be invoking your scripts with your custom application. Chances are, that syntax is ambiguous anyway which is why it isn't supported as is.

[Here are some examples of using the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) in PowerShell](https://github.com/dfinke/PowerShellASTDemo) from [Doug Finke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110865/doug-finke).